# "Building of [ noun ]" vs "Building [ noun ]"

Tags: gerunds, phrase-choice

I was asked by one of my coworkers if there is a difference between "Building of human relationships" and "Building human relationships".

I couldn't find any discussion on this topic through google searches or even searching specific sites.

My gut reaction is that "Building of A" puts emphasis on the product, where as "Building A" emphasizes the process, but I don't know if that's correct.

I know that "Building of A" can only be used as a noun, whereas "building A" can be used in verb phrases as well as a noun. Is there any difference beyond that?

Answer (score 0):

In '[the] building of human relationships', *building* is a gerund, functioning as a noun referring to the process.

In 'building human relationships', it is the present participle of the verb *to build.*

Comment: What about in the case of something like this:
"The building of human relationships is an important part of personal growth."
vs
"Building human relationships is an important part of personal growth."
Is there any real difference between those two constructions? Are there any situations where we would use one over the other?

Comment: No, I don't think so, for either question.